# PayPal REST API PHP options if my host refuses to update their OpenSSL command line?

Tags: php, ssl, encryption, paypal, exec

I finally got my site working on my laptop, uploaded it and am getting the error:

```
 exception 'PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException' with message 'Unsupported SSL protocol version'
```

So I'm thinking the host having:

```
TLS 1.0OpenSSL/0.9.8bOpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008
```

is my problem most likely.

My question: If my host (who shall remain nameless for now) refuses to update `OpenSSL` is there anything I can do to fix/work around and avoid getting another host?

I've had a quick look at https://www.madboa.com/geek/openssl/ but its a bit out of my depth to quickly know if I could download a newer version of `OpenSSL` configure it on the shared server and run the commands to encrypt/decrypt messages with PayPal directly with the exec command.

Yes I know, if it worked it would be a dogs breakfast but it might see me through until my host eventually pulls their finger out from where it currently is.

Comment: Does your website has a SSL certificate?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, TBH I don't know... (I'm learning a lot over the last week or so) there is a shared certificate provided by the host but obviously the certificate is in their name.  As part of my development I have created a free certificate using OpenSSL but I did that for the old way of doing things using the listener.  I have re-done the buynow buttons etc now to use the REST API.  I think I don't need a certificate just the PayPal clientID and clientSecret?

Comment: Are you working on localhost?

Comment: I have it all working on my laptop, it is on the shared webserver it is not working

Comment: Common sense has prevailed and my host has moved me to their new server, I am curious if using openSSL and passing the messages back and forth encrypting and decrypting would have been possible but for now it i not needed (thank you)